# Code on pentagonal numbers takes too long to execute

Tags: python, numbers

I'm trying to solve problem 44 from Project Euler (https://projecteuler.net/problem=44) which states

> Pentagonal numbers are generated by the formula, Pn=n(3n−1)/2. The first ten pentagonal numbers are:
>
> 1, 5, 12, 22, 35, 51, 70, 92, 117, 145, ...
>
> It can be seen that P4 + P7 = 22 + 70 = 92 = P8. However, their difference, 70 − 22 = 48, is not pentagonal.
>
> Find the pair of pentagonal numbers, Pj and Pk, for which their sum and difference are pentagonal and D = |Pk − Pj| is minimised; what is the value of D?

This is my approach but it takes too long to execute. It took over 15 minutes before I killed it. Since I don't know the answer this is a hit and try method where I check every number below 10000.

```
pentagonal = []
for i in range (1,10001):
    x = (i*(3*i - 1))/2
    pentagonal.append(x)

for i in pentagonal:
    for j in pentagonal:
        x = i - j
        y = i + j
        if x in pentagonal and y in pentagonal:
            print("(",i,":",j,")")
```

Comment: What Python's version do you use? Python 3.x+ or Python 2.7.x ?

Comment: I use Python 3.

Comment: @Riptide How do you derive the upper limit (i.e. 10000), or it is some sort of random guess?

Comment: @RaviRaj yes 10000 was just a random guess on my part

Answer (score 1):

Search large lists is not efficient with **in** command. The best way is to use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html) module.

```
from bisect import bisect_left

pentagonal = []
for n in range(1, 10000):
    p = int((n*(3*n - 1))/2)
    pentagonal.append(p)


def bisect_search(lst, item):
    ''' it is used for sorted lists'''
    return (item <= lst[-1]) and (lst[bisect_left(lst, item)] == item)


for i in pentagonal:
    for j in pentagonal:
        diff = abs(i - j)
        sam = i + j
        if bisect_search(pentagonal, sam) and bisect_search(pentagonal, diff):
            print("(", i, ":", j, ")")
```

The smallest difference comes from Pk = 7042750 and Pj = 1560090  and it is D = 5482600